# Question for auto-resizing Textarea using VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, textarea

I'm trying to let the text area automatically adjust its height when the text value changes:

```
<textarea ref="textarea" v-model="message"> </textarea>
```

I used a watcher to monitor the component variable "message" associated with the text area. Whenever the message changes, a function will be triggered to adjust the textarea height:

```js
watch: {
  message: function(){
    this.$refs.textarea.style.height="auto";
    this.$refs.textarea.style.height = this.$refs.textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  },
}
```

The code works well if I manually type inside the box. However, if I use methods to update the textarea variable "message", the size of the box does not update correctly.

To make it more clear, I created a fiddle project: https://jsfiddle.net/ttl66046/9nycdq60/4/
codepen here: https://codepen.io/ttl66046/pen/eYGqJWm

There are two buttons underneath the textbox. Each button is associated with a short text. Ideally, the height of the textbox should be updated based upon the button you clicked (the text you choose). What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects of the watcher are not rendered until the *next* render cycle. The `message` watcher sets `height` twice (once to `auto` and then *immediately* overwrites it with `scrollHeight`), but the component does not re-render in  between each setting.

The key is to update the `height` in the next render cycle with a [`$nextTick()` callback](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#nexttick):

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    message: function() {
      this.$refs.textarea.style.height = "auto";
               
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.$refs.textarea.style.height = this.$refs.textarea.scrollHeight + 'px';
      })
    }
  }
}
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/abVoNdW)

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved my life! I see the issue here. So basically, the issue of my code is that "this.$refs.textarea.scrollHeight" has not finished rendered yet. $nextTick() just wait let the function in the watcher wait after next cycle (or let the textbox finish rendering).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an auto-resize textarea in VueJS 3 using the `<script setup>` syntax:

**Create a Vue component (e.g., ChatMessage.vue):**

```
<template>
  <div class="chat-message">
    <textarea
      v-model="message"
      @input="adjustTextarea"
      ref="textarea"
      class="autoresize"
      placeholder="Type a message..."
    ></textarea>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const message = ref('');
const textarea = ref(null);

const adjustTextarea = () => {
  textarea.value.style.height = 'auto';
  textarea.value.style.height = `${textarea.value.scrollHeight}px`;
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.autoresize {
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 120px;
}
</style>
```

You can use this component in your Vue application like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ChatMessage />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChatMessage from "./ChatMessage.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ChatMessage
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add following code in css:

```css
textarea {
    width:200px;
    resize:none;
  }
```

Comment: It is not working. The height of the text area still does not change correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "+" row and "-" row on change TEXT use Vue3 (Composition API for me):

```
            <textarea
               id="newComm"
               class="form-control"
               name="comment"
               placeholder="Some text you want"
               cols="30"
               :rows="rowsHeight"
               wrap="soft"
               v-model.trim="newCommText"
               @input="changeRows"
               :style="'resize: none; overflow: hidden; line-height: '+lineHeight+'px;'"
        ></textarea>

    setup() {
    /*--------your code here--------*/

    const newCommText = ref(null)
    const rowsHeightStart = ref(5)
    const rowsHeight = ref(rowsHeightStart.value)
    const lineHeight = ref(25)
    function changeRows (event) {
        rowsHeight.value = event.target.value.split("\n").length > rowsHeightStart.value ? event.target.value.split("\n").length : rowsHeightStart.value
    }

    return {
         rowsHeight, lineHeight, newCommText,
        changeRows
    }
```